# How to show permission dialog again

Tags: uwp

I'm new to UWP and I have problem: how do I show the permission dialog again if the user doesn't grant it?

[image]
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiNKm.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the user says "No" to your prompt, then Windows will not prompt again. This is to avoid users being spammed with multiple notifications. If the user wants to change their mind, they have to go to Settings -> Privacy and then enable your app from there.

You can provide a link for them that jumps into settings with the `ms-settings:privacy-microphone` URI. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) for more info.